# Carousel captions not overlaying image on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap carousel example works great without images, and with images in a laptop browser. But on mobile devices, the captions don't overlay the images, which pushes all of the content down.  Can you tell me how to fix this?

https://main.thcguard.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this block of code will solve your problem, add them on your custom .css file...
let me know if you have any questions

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .carousel-caption .btn {
    padding: .3rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .carousel-control-prev,
  .carousel-control-next {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-item {
    height: 330px;
  }
}


/*max-width:680px*/

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 220px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div with the class "carousel-caption" is absolutely positioned. I would create a media query for your mobile breakpoint and then either set that div to position relative and then kill the bottom: 20px; OR keep it absolutely positioned and adjust the bottom value to your liking.